# Closed-form expression for definite integrals involving modified Bessel functions K_1 and K_0

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, bessel-functions

I am attempting to derive a closed-form expression for the following two integrals involving the modified Bessel functions $K_1$ and $K_0$, but I can't find a solution (I don't know if there is one). Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{y} K_1\Big( \frac{y^2+1}{y}\Big) dy$$

and

$$\int_{1}^\infty  K_0\Big( \frac{y^2+1}{y}\Big) dy.$$

I have already tried a change of variables but it seems to get worse….

Comment: I was informed recently (I think by @TheAmplitwist) that Unicode characters in titles are essentially invisible to search, so I changed K₀ and K₁ to K_0 and K_1 to improve searchability.

Comment: most integrals of special functions cannot be evaluated in closed form; do you have an indication why these would be exceptions?

Comment: @LSpice,thank you very much!

Comment: @CarloBeenakker,There are known expressions involving modified Bessel functions, like the one shown below.If I could find something similar for my integrals, it would be great !         $$\int_{0}^\infty x^{p}K_n(x/b)dx=2^{p-1}b^{p+1}\Gamma(\frac{1+p+n}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{1+p-n}{2})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $y=e^t$ turns your first integral into
$$
\int_0^\infty K_1(2\cosh(t))dt.
$$
The formula [10.32.17](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E17) on DLMF reads
$$
K_\mu(z)K_\nu(z)=2\int_0^\infty K_{\mu\pm\nu}(2z\cosh(t))\cosh((\mu\mp\nu)t)dt
$$
for $\Re(z)>0$. Choosing here $+$ at $\pm$ and $-$ at $\mp$ and taking $\mu=\nu=\frac12$ and $z=1$ gives
$$
\int_0^\infty K_1(2\cosh(t))dt=\frac12K_{\frac12}(1)^2;
$$
by [10.39.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.39.E2) this is in fact $\frac\pi{4e^2}$, so
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac1yK_1\left(\frac{y^2+1}y\right)dy=\frac\pi{4e^2}.
$$

As for the second integral, the same substitution turns it into
$$
\int_0^\infty K_0(2\cosh(t))e^tdt,
$$
and the same formula gives
$$
\int_0^\infty K_0(2\cosh(t))\cosh(t)dt=\frac\pi{4e^2},
$$
so, since $e^t=\cosh(t)+\sinh(t)$, it remains to determine $\int_0^\infty K_0(2\cosh(t))\sinh(t)dt$, which is the same as $\frac12\int_2^\infty K_0(z)dz$. Now by [10.43.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43.E2),
$$
\int K_0(z)dz=\frac{\pi z}2\left(K_0(z)L_{-1}(z)+K_1(z)L_0(z)\right)
$$
where $L_\nu(z)$ are the [modified Struve functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function). This then gives
$$
\int_1^\infty K_0\left(\frac{y^2+1}y\right)dy=\frac\pi4\left(1+\frac1{e^2}-2\left(K_0(2)L_{-1}(2)+K_1(2)L_0(2)\right)\right).
$$
I don't know whether this can be simplified any further.

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე, Thank you so much; I was struggling with these integrals!

Comment: @vbarros Pleasure is mine, as they say :)